# WP-Hook - On log in send email private content plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, email

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the Wordpress Hooks or Filters in order that I can make the functionality for the plugin I am using PrivateContent to how I need it.

The Users are not WORDPRESS users in the plugin so I cannot monitor them very well however the plugin works as I need it. I need to create a hook which when the user enters their username and password to log in it sends a an email to me so I can see when people are logging in or not may be the case.

I have been reading the documentation and I think that I will have to use the pc_user_login function.

http://www.lcweb.it/privatecontent/public-api?section=actions#pc_user_login

Now when I log in i get an email with a number which relates to the user using User_id However if i use $username then i don't receive an email.

```
  add_action('pc_user_login', 'custom_mail');

   function custom_mail($user_id){
    global $pc_users;
    // Do what you need to get vars
    $to = 'dillonjenkins@lifetimeweb.co.uk';
    $subject = 'User has Logged In';
    $message = ($user_id);


    wp_mail($to,$subject,$message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pièce of code that you can add to functions.php

```
 add_action('pc_user_login', 'custom_mail');

 function custom_mail($user_id){
        global $pc_users;
        // Do what you need to get vars
        wp_mail($to,$subject,$message);
 }
```

Arrange the code to fit your needs

Comment: Thank you @Benoti, I will try this out! You have saved me if this works!!

Comment: So i can get a better understanding, the add_action is that saying when user logs in custom mail will happen? and then in wp_mail i will have to define my information is that correct?

Comment: Yes of course, i don't know what you want to send with the mail. You can grab the user info with the user ID passes through parameter and wp native functions.

Comment: I want to send the Username so that i can create a sort of hacked event log, as i can't find a plugin for this.